# On select / click event of a Ext.RadioGroup

Tags: extjs

Again Im probably being stupid, I am having trouble with listener events of objects.

I have:

```
new Ext.form.Radio({
                    boxLabel:'Yes',
                    id: 'car_price_type_yes',
                    name: 'car_price_type',
                    value: 1,
                    listeners: {
                        select: function (e) {
                            alert('x');
                        }
                    }
                })
```

I am trying to get the alert to appear when I click the radio button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the treatment of radio buttons as some kind of non-normal entity.  They don't seem call listeners at all.

After wading thru the documentation, forums, source, and everything else, I stumbled on a mention of the handler method and it seems you have to declare them to have a handler (like below) if you want to detect the "click" event, or the "change" event, or the "select" event.  The only "event" I've been able to get 4.1.3 to actually produce is to call my handler function, none of the other event names seem to produce anything.  Numerous people in the docs point out that change does not always fire, I never managed to get it to fire at all.

```
{
    boxLabel: 'Field Based'
    , name: 'alert_type'
    , inputValue: 'field'
    , xtype: "radiofield"
    , listeners: {
        // won't be called
        click: function(a,b,c,d) {  
            console.log("FB",a,b,c,d);
        }
        // won't be called
        ,change: function(a,b,c,d) {  
            console.log("Change",a,b,c,d);
        }
        // won't be called
        , select: function(field, newValue, oldValue) { 
            console.log(field, "Radio Selected ", newValue, "to", oldValue);
        }
        // won't be called
        , check: function(field, newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log(field, "Radio Checked ", newValue, "to", oldValue);
        }
    }
    // WILL BE CALLED
    , handler: function(field, state) {
        console.log(field, state, c, d)
    }
},
```

The handler will produce logging output like:

```
constructor {boxLabel: "Field Based", name: "alert_type", inputValue: "field", listeners: null, handler: function…}
true
```

Answer (score -2):

You want the `check` event.  You really should become more familiar with the [docs](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/), it will help with this kind of question.

EDIT: Seems that people are unhappy with this answer. OK, as of Ext 4.x it seems that the [`change`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Radio-event-change) event is what you want on radios/checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry but when I change 'select' to check, I still do not get the alert. I have also tried taking it outside of the listeners brace.

Comment: You must have some other issue because I copied your code above, changed the event to 'check' and I got the alert as expected.

Comment: If your extjs docs didn't suck so badly this wouldn't be so hard to figure out.  Your docs http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Radio don't have a check event on radio buttons.

Comment: They are not "my" docs, but thanks for the down vote. Seems that since I answered this question almost 3 years ago, the docs may have changed — imagine that! Perhaps complain to Sencha, rather than in the comments of ancient SO threads.

Comment: I have complained, they answer "read the docs" just like you.  And since you were making commits to their SVN, I assumed you worked for them.

Comment: I was a cofounder originally and left in late 2008.  When I answered this question (3 years ago) the link and docs were accurate. I can't review every answer I have here every time Sencha does a release to verify links.  I have edited my answer with the new link as of Ext 4. Again, take your anger to Sencha, not me.